# MySQL Workbench - error unserializing grt data

Tags: mysql

Está aparecendo pra mim um erro ao abrir um projeto no MySql Workbench.

```
error unserializing grt data
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com membros que passaram pelo mesmo problema no Stack Overflow Inglês, é só reiniciar o Workbench que resolve.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890021/mysql-workbench-error-opening-eer

Comment: Reiniciei e executei como administrador, e volto a funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema, apenas reiniciei, sem administrador, e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Funcionou para mim também depois de reiniciar, Obrigado!